# Trying to get selenium to access tags from a popup

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Am new to python and web scraping but felt like taking on a task as this one. Could you please take a look at my code and identify what exactly am doing wrong:
The code just keeps printing "Null" when I know there is data it is supposed to pick. Also, it gives a timeout exception after two or three loops. Please help me out. I am well and truly stuck.

````
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from time import sleep
import csv

filename = "Websites.csv"
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Name", "Website"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Hp/Downloads/chromedriver.exe")
myurl = "https://portal-akh.de/bueroverzeichnis/liste/suchergebnisse.php"
driver.get(myurl)

Row_Num = range(2,3412)


for i in Row_Num:
    Rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='table suchergebnisse']/tbody/tr")
    
    
    try:
        Rows[i].click()
   
        Name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='modal hide fade in']/div/h3/font/font")
        
        Website  = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='modal hide fade in']/div[@class='modal-body']/p/a").get_attribute('href')
        with open(filename, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(Name.text + "," + Website + "\n")
    except AttributeError:
        print('Null')
        with open(filename, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write("Null" + "\n")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('Null')
        with open(filename, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write("Null" + "\n")
    finally:
        el = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda d: d.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='modal hide fade in']/div/button[@type='button']"))
        el.click()
        
        sleep(10)

driver.close()
file.close()```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Documents\Data Science & Analytics\PycharmProjects\Selenium\Member Scrape.py", line 41, in <module>
    el = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda d: d.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='modal hide fade in']/div/button[@type='button']"))
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
````

Comment: Well, you're masking the exceptions with all of those try...excepts.

Comment: Your script can't locate the "website" element

Comment: He just wants to write some .text and an element's ahref value to a csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what link you are pulling from but I'd do it something like this.
All you need to do is check for the element to grab with if driver.find_element_by_xpath(): then either set it to NULL or whatever you want.

```
filename = "Websites.csv"
driver.get("https://portal-akh.de/bueroverzeichnis/liste/suchergebnisse.php")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
#Bring this outside the loop
Rows = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table suchergebnisse']/tbody/tr")))
#Skipped 0
#Make len(Rows) smaller for testing
Row_Num = range(1,len(Rows))
datalist = [[]] 
for i in Row_Num:
    try:
        Rows[i].click()
        time.sleep(5)
        Name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='modal hide fade in' and @aria-hidden='false']/div/h3")))
        #print(Name.text)
        Website='NULL'
        #Website = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='modal hide fade in' and @aria-hidden='false']/div[@class='modal-body']/p/a"))).get_attribute('href')
        #print(Website)
        datalist.append([Name.text,Website])
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='modal hide fade in' and @aria-hidden='false']//button[@class='close']"))).click()
    except Exception as e:
        #datalist.append(['NULL','NULL'])
        print(i,e)
        pass
df = pd.DataFrame(datalist,columns =['Name', 'Link'])
print(df)
df.to_csv(filename, index = False)
```

Outputs

```
                  Name  Link
                  None  None
        Abeling, Sören  NULL
  Abendroth, Christian  NULL
       Achilles, Heiko  NULL
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for not adding comments to my code. Something new learnt. :)

Comment: Thanks Arundeep. The href links am trying to get are not in  all the rows. They are found in some but not all. eg: row 32. How do I modify the code to grab those and fill in "Null" for those that do not have?

Comment: Well first you check if driver.find_element_by_xpath('yourpath'): then you can just set it to 'null' instead in an else.